# Bootstrap 3 collapsed navbar menu links don't work on Chrome for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

As the title says, Bootstrap 3 collapsed navbar menu links don't work on Chrome for Android. When you click on a link the menu simply closes. I'm experiencing this issue with *Chrome 34.0.1847.114* (currently the latest version) It works fine on Desktop and Firefox mobile.

I've searched around but couldn't find any fix. Everything I find is related to Bootstrap 2.3 or early versions of Bootstrap 3 and they don't work.

To test this just go to http://getbootstrap.com/ the links on the collapsed menu don't work.

Any feedback on this?

UPDATE: it's working again. It seems a browser glitch.